# CE Cache only caching logged user

Tags: ce-cache

Installed CE Cache and deployed. Funny thing is that it only caches something when i'm logged on (changed to cache in db and found out). If i use another browser to simulate a logged off user, it doesn't cache.. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh! Found out that this option in config.php should be set to "yes":

```
$config['ce_cache_fragment_logged_in_only'] = 'no';
```